Editing a form in ant design in frontend application(React) and Graphql in the backend
I am a junior coder and still really struggling with the basic.
I will try to explain what I am trying to do step by step:

I have a form already filled with data.
click on edit the form.
there are some required fields meaning they can not be empty in the form and there are other fields that can be left empty.
The user can edit any fields.
Then, the user can click cancel button.
when the user clicks on cancel buttons; there are a pop up that opens to tell that user you have  choices; discard the changes or another button to save the changes.
if the user click on discard; it will rever to the original data and go back to the original data without any changes.
if the user click on saved changes; if the user make changes to required and non required fields; the changes will be saved. If the user left some required fields empty; it will not saved anything.

What I want to accomplish is that the user can modify non required data, but if they modify required data in away that make them empty; they save button should save the changes and any empty fields should rever back to the original data before editing. I appreciate any advice.
I have tried to use fieldForm.submit and fieldFor.getfieldsValues()
